# Invalid credentials for database 'Database Name'. MongoDB 2.6.2

Tags: c#, mongodb, connection-string, mongodb-query

I am using monogdb 2.6.2 and trying to create administrator user account in monogdb server.

User details are as follows:-

[image]

I am able to access any database with these database credentials in Mongo shell but when I am trying with the same database credentials through application I am getting an error.

**Invalid credentials for database 'Database Name'**

Database connection string:-

**"mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27011";**

Can somebody please help?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Please have a look at the two methods which are trying to create new collection in the database.

[image]

Now when I tried to login with the same username and password which is **-u admin -p admin**, mongo shell is giving me unauthorized user error.

Then I created a new user with new username and password which is **-u sa -p root** and i did the same steps again.

It is allowing the user to access in mongo shell but unauthorized to access with the same username and password from the application.

[image]

Comment: can you Show us the code part where you try to connect to the database?

Comment: @IsThatSo Please have a look at updated question.

Comment: he already said "I am able to access any database with these database credentials in Mongo shell but when I am trying with the same database credentials through application I am getting an error."

Comment: @DavidG What sort of permissions? I have already added roles to the user. Please look at the command line picture.

Comment: How do you connect with the shell?

Comment: is your password really admin?

Comment: Yes.. Let me show you that snapshot also.

Comment: @IsThatSo Please have a look at the updated  question.

Comment: What version of the csharp driver are you using?

Comment: @helmy  Csharp driver version - 1.7.0.4714

Answer (score 2):

You need to authenticate to the correct database. Your user exists in the admin database, so authenticate to the admin database using a connection string like

```
mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27011/admin
```

Comment: But if I have given the role of "readwriteAnyDatabase" then It should be applicable to all the other databases. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: You have read/write access to any database, but you should still authenticate to the admin database where the user record resides. Does it not work to do that? If so, do you get a different error message?